# Android mobile not detecting wireless network created on my laptop

Tags: android, windows, wifi, android-wireless

I use HTC Explorer and  I have created an ad-hoc network on my laptop. Although other laptops are easily able to connect to it, my mobile device is not even detecting the Wi-Fi.

How can I connect my mobile to the Wi-Fi hotspot on my laptop (running Windows 7)?

Answer (score 12):

There is an alternative solution involving "Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter":

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=NAME key=PASSWORD
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

For additional details and troubleshooting see this post on XDA-developers:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/general/guide-alternate-to-ad-hoc-wi-fi-network-t1924911

Answer (score 2):

Ad Hoc networks are not supported natively by Android devices, unless you get your device **rooted** and make some tricks in the underlying linux system.

There are a lot of pages talking about that:

http://dev.gadgeticworld.com/how-to-connect-android-devices-to-adhoc-network/

http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/3372947/connect-android-phone-ad-hoc-network/

http://code.google.com/p/adhoc-on-android/

You can try this at your risk:

http://www.arenddeboer.com/wifi-ad-hoc-enabler-for-android

Comment: Poster was not asking about hosting an ad hoc network on an android device - you have it backwards :0